# Problem styling the article HTML5 tag using the modernizr javascript library

Tags: css, html, modernizr

An annoying problem I'm having with the modernizr script. This script is supposed to enable Internet Explorer to style the new HTML 5 tags, but in my code the header tag is styled, but the article tag is not. If I use a DIV with the ID "article" and apply the styles, they **are** visible, so it seems as if modernizr doesn't work for article tags? I am using IE 8 to test this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="~Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    header,footer,nav,section {display: block;}
    article, #article {border:1px solid red;}
    header {height: 95px;border-bottom: 8px solid #6b6b6d;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="page">

    <header>
        LOGO | Title
    </header>

    <article>
        <h2>article element</h2>
    </article>

    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="article">
        <h2>div with id article</h2>
    </div>

</div>

<footer>
    footertext
</footer>
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` should be inside your `<head></head>`.

Comment: @dosboy ; thanks, you're right. It didn't solve the problem unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `article { display: block; }` to your CSS. You could just change the first line of your CSS to:

```
header, footer, nav, section, article { display: block; }
```

That will solve the problem.

Comment: +1. I was having exactly the same problem. FYI, I also added `aside, hgroup` as Chrome's user-agent stylesheet has these defined as `display:block;` as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! It had to be something simple, but I didn't think of defining article as a block type element. (And I hadn't noticed it was missing from the css declarations)

Comment: It seems, with the latest Modernizr (2.5.2) it automatically injects the necessary styles to do this.

Answer (score -4):

I think you're using the wrong library.

*"Modernizr does not add missing functionality to browsers; instead, it detects native availability of features and offers you a way to maintain a fine level of control over your site regardless of a browser’s capabilities." http://www.modernizr.com/*

If you're interested in what you **can** do with Modernizr, ALA has a clear article on how to effectively use it: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/

Please read the top answer to this other question: [HTML5shiv vs Dean Edwards IE7-js vs Modernizr - which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855294/html5shiv-vs-dean-edwards-ie7-js-vs-modernizr-which-to-choose)

I think the **html5shiv** library might be more fitting to your issue.

Comment: Incorrect. Modernizr includes the HTML5 Shiv, so that’s not the issue.