# IE not styling HTML5 tags (with shiv)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm trying to style a `<header>` and it's not working in IE.  I'm using Modernizr, but i've tried the shiv by itself.

Example code

```
<section>
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>
  <p>Body</p>
</section>
```

Styled with:

```
section {
    border: 2px dotted black;
    padding: 0.25em;
}

header h1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I expect a border around the header and section content, but instead there is just an '[' looking border and the header is beneath it.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: @feela -- are you *sure* about that? Modernizr *does* include the Shiv functionality, and it works for at least IE8 and IE7. (we're using it for a site that needs to work in IE7, and it's fine). See this answer for more on what it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855294/html5shiv-vs-dean-edwards-ie7-js-vs-modernizr-which-to-choose/3855343#3855343

Comment: @feeela is incorrect. We use this and it works from IE7 up.

Comment: @Spudley @Michael Irigoyen Sorry, I think its too late. Myself had answered this on a [different question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11729/whats-the-difference-between-modernizr-and-html5shiv/11740#11740)…

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With IE, even with the shiv, you need to declare the HTML 5 elements as block elements. I use this line for Internet Explorer, but you can modify it for the elements you need.

```
header,nav,article,footer,section,aside,figure,figcaption{display:block}
```

From the [Modernizr Documentation](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie):

> You’ll also probably want to set many of these elements to `display:block;`

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what style you're trying to impose on the element.
So as James Long put it before, custom elements are `inline` by default. For IE8 you also could give the element a border by adding `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes custom elements (which is how we convince IE to use HTML5 tags) are `inline` by default. Try adding the following piece of CSS:

```
section,
header {
    display: block;
}
```