# IE7 & IE8 don't apply CSS to HTML5

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've been struggling to get HTML5 tags to work on IE7 & IE8. Finally I have used html5shiv.js and the problem was solved. The elements displays on screen as they are displayed on any modern browser.

But for now, I don't know why IE7 & IE8 won't apply the css rules I have declared. For example:

```
header
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Does not apply black background color to the header tag nor any background color. When I search for that declarations on IE7 & IE8 it appears to be undeclared, but when I try IE on IE9 mode, that same css rule I have declared do appear and styles the element with black background color. Any help or solutions will be really appreciated.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602758/ie-not-styling-html5-tags-with-shiv

Comment: ie7 and ie8 don't support that tag yet, so they will just ignore it when parsing the HTML. When you want to write cross-browser code which supports legacy internet explorers, you should do without the new semantic HTML5 tags. There aren't many applications which make use of them anyway (yet).

Comment: Yes, html5 tags are ignored on old browsers. But html5shiv did the work for that. So I didn't have to wrap things in divs but did it on a more semantically correct markup with the new tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to reproduce. Using http://browserstack.com, I tested the code below in both IE7 and IE8 running natively on Windows XP, and both of them applied the CSS as expected, properly:

I can only suspect that you missed something, somewhere, and as such were not getting the results you were expecting. Try reducing your project to a small test case, as I have done here. Be sure that you have referenced all of your appropriate dependencies.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Elements in IE7/8</title>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">
            header {
                background-color: #000000;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>Hello, world!</header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You sir, are right. I'm working with symfony and all I had to do after seeing  your working example was deleting symfony cache. It worked as expected after that. But still, weird thing it didn't show the styles on IE7 & IE8 but in every other browser with the old cache, maybe it had to be something with cache-ing html5shiv.

Thank you very mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you,

All Browsers Render HTML5 Mark-up Correctly – Even IE6:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have a cross-browser way to style these elements while still retaining their semantic meaning, you could wrap each of them in a div and apply the CSS to that div as a class. Most use-cases for semantic markup don't need styles anyway - their primary purpose is to convey those informations to machines which is conveyed to humans through the CSS styling.

Answer (score -1):

well you have to check header area like

if you add some comments before

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

then also you get the issue like css class missing or attributes