# I can use footer tag from HTML5 in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I found something strange in my website... I'm using HTML5 and this script to use in olders browsers.

```
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

When I use `<article>,<section>` it works but when I use `<footer>` it doesn't.

I don't know the reason.

The others tags have the open tag and close tag.... This is the html code
Header:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
       <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>            
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            activaMapa = 0;
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Footer Code

```
<footer class="pie">
    <p><a href="mywebsite.html" title="myWeb" target="_blank">Web Site</a></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: @Vucko markup is not required, `<footer>` is simply not supported in `ie8`

Comment: @starvator the OP uses [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and if you look at its documentation, you'll see: _The HTML5 Shiv enables use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy Internet Explorer and provides basic HTML5 styling for Internet Explorer 6-9_.

Comment: @Marcos did you tried [adding the `diplay:block` style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6602804/1763929) to the `footer`?

Comment: @Vucko Yes, I have this in my css, with the others html5 tags

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers doesn't support HTML5 tags. For this, you can use libraries like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/).

These libraries will provide support for older browsers bearing the HTML5 tags.

Comment: The OP said thet he's using html5shim.

Comment: Yes, I know it... I'm using html5shim and works with others tags...(article, section...) my website works good except footer

Comment: @ASHISHKUMARTiwary Did you notice that your edit was 1) useless 2) harmful - it broke the referenced links markdown ? Please learn the SO markdown syntax first before go deep into editing.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `html5shim` to `html5shiv`

```html
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Hope this may work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses!

I found the problem...I'm looking my settings in IE and I've the scripting disabled... I activated and works!

Thanks for all!

Answer (score -1):

A good way to see if a tag is supported or not is by using [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=footer), and in this case, no, `<footer>` is not supported in `ie8`.

Instead, try using

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

and for your css instead of

```
footer {
    ...
}
```

use

```
#footer {
    ...
}
```